# InfoPath form calculations work in client but not in browser

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-services

I have an InfoPath 2010 form that needs to be deployed via SharePoint forms services in Internet Explorer. The form contains some calculations that should update whenever a field is changed. The calculations were created via functions in InfoPath Designer, not in a code-behind.

When I run the form locally in my InfoPath client, the calculations update when a field is changed as expected ("refresh value when formula is recalculated" is checked). However, when I deploy the form to SharePoint and create a new form in a forms library, the calculations don't always update until I click an unrelated checkbox on the form, which forces a round trip to the server.

Do I need to create a "calculate" button that users click to force a server round trip? Or is there a way to make those calculations fire every time in the browser, like they do in the InfoPath client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell InfoPath that changes to the field should result in a server round trip.

- Select the source control.
- In the ribbon tab Control Tools Properties click Control properties
- On the Browser Form tab select Always below Postback settings

[image]

Comment: While this is useful, the poster is speaking to webforms, which require the focus to leave the field before the postback occurs, so even if this is done, unless the user changes focus to another field, the calculation will not update. For this reason, sometimes a dummy "recalculate" button (or even a functional one) can be useful.